# What are the characters that I need to escape in a SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, escaping

What are the characters that I need to check for and escape when inserting a string?

```sql
INSERT INTO gamedata (gamename, url, dlink) 
VALUES ('mady's run', 'http://www.sdfa.com', 'http://extabit.com/sdf')</code>
```

How do I escape these characters?
I'm using C# and managing database with SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

Comment: how about using parameters and forget about escaping characters?

Comment: Checkout this link for a good example.. also there are a lot of examples on the web.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170676/storing-the-url-in-sqlserver-2005-using-c-sharp-codedata-sets

Answer (score 22):

Don't escape them. Just don't include the values in your SQL at all. Instead, use *parameterized SQL* and supply the values directly for the parameters. No escaping, no quoting, no conversions - and no risk of SQL injection attacks.

See [the documentation for `SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for an example.

You should apply this to *all* values - not just ones which you anticipate having "special" characters. It separates the code (SQL) from the data (the values), avoids SQL injection attacks, and also avoids unnecessary conversions (which can really cause problems for date/time values and numbers, if you're not careful).

Comment: I've read about parameters but haven't used it yet.. thanks guys. I'm gonna put it in my code.

Comment: @KaushikDB While you're at it you should check out LINQ. Esp since it'll paratamertize your SQL queries for you automatically.

Comment: I've used the sqlcommand.parameters and it worked like a charm. thanks a bunch guys. @kittoes i'll also check out LINQ. thanks.